# Flutter. How to display 3 pages in PageView with Opacity and resize

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-pageview, flutter-opacity

Hello everyone I am developing an application on Flutter. But I faced a big (for me) challenge. I need to implement a custom `PageView`, but I have no idea how to do it at all.

I tried different solutions from pub.dev: `scroll_snap_list`, `carousel_slider`, but they did not suit me, I will be glad of any help or advice. Thanks[image: This is the result I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: All you need is a `PageController`, set `viewportFraction` to resize the pages, and use the controller in `Opacity` widget

Answer (score 1):

Check out this video [Flutter Carousel Slider with PageView and Hero Animation](https://youtu.be/R_XjwaSOFmg?si=EefNxTmSy9NV1kcd), the results are quite similar to what you want.

This is my modification code from the video above to get the resize & opacity effect:

(Runnable in dartpad)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  int _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _pageController =
        PageController(initialPage: _currentPage, viewportFraction: 0.7);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Find Your Style",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        fontSize: 30)),
              ),
            ),
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 0.85,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: dataList.length,
                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _pageController,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return carouselView(index);
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget carouselView(int index) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _pageController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        double value = 0.0;
        if (_pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = index.toDouble() - (_pageController.page ?? 0);
          value = value.abs();
          value = (value * 0.2).clamp(-1, 1);
          print("value $value index $index");
        }
        return Transform.scale(
          scale: 1 - value,
          child: AnimatedOpacity(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            child: carouselCard(dataList[index]),
            opacity: 1 - value*2,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget carouselCard(DataModel data) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Hero(
              tag: data.imageName,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                            data.imageName,
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      boxShadow: const [
                        BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(0, 4),
                            blurRadius: 4,
                            color: Colors.black26)
                      ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Text(
            data.title,
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black45,
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            "\$${data.price}",
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DataModel {
  final String title;
  final String imageName;
  final double price;
  DataModel(
    this.title,
    this.imageName,
    this.price,
  );
}

List<DataModel> dataList = [
  DataModel("Short Dress", "assets/images/fashion2.jpeg", 300.8),
  DataModel("Office Formals", "assets/images/fashion1.jpeg", 245.2),
  DataModel("Casual Jeans", "assets/images/fashion4.png", 168.2),
  DataModel("Jeans Skirt", "assets/images/fashion3.jpg", 136.7),
];
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]